# Degrees of freedom in emmeans package

Tags: post-hoc, degrees-of-freedom, lsmeans

This is my first time uploading, so please bear with me.

I am currently trying to do a post-hoc test with three interaction term (time X support X NFC).
We did a follow-up on participants' well-being for four time points (Time1 ~ Time 4), and assessed their support and their NFC once in Time 1.

My model is a mixed model (used lme function) with time as a random slope, and participants' ID as a random intercept. The dependent variable is well-being. I ran an emmeans as below:

[image]

The question I have is that post-hoc analysis shows df that are either 1825 or 3005. However, between time points, participants were lost (N = time 1: 1833 > time 2: 1191 > time 3: 984 > time 4: 842; total observations are N = 4850) and I can't really understand why the degrees of freedom are same over all the time conditions.

I have been struggling to understand this output for days and would highly appreciate if someone explain this to me. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The df are higher when you compare two times with the other factors the same, because that is a within-subject comparison. But with so many df, there is really no difference between 1825 df and 3005 df, or 1000 df for that matter. So understanding the df is not something to worry about here.

Comment: The df are the same because your model (not shown) evidently pools the variance estimates together. I imagine you have ONE estimate of residual SD and ONE estimate of subject SD. Do `VarCorr(model5)` to see those estimates. BTW, are you really sure you want to compare all combinations of those three factors?

Comment: Thank you for the comments:) I really appreciate it!

My model is:


AFFECT~1+PO+SES+age+sex+support*NFC*(time+I(time^2)+I(time^3)), random=~(time+I(time^2)+I(time^3))|ID


NFC is the moderator, and support*time is how supporting someone led to different affective well-being at each time points. Therefore, I am trying to look into three-way interaction of NFC*support*time.

Comment: Like what you said, I am also a bit worried about comparing all combinations of the three factors (and whether it is a good approach when cubic term is included as a random slope)....But my advisor asked me to at least look into it. If there is a better approach, please do tell me! I would appreciate any input on this matter:)

Answer (score 2):

Based on a comment as well as the OP, I gather that two of the three predictors involved in the interaction of interest are continuous covariates. One of them, `NFC`, appears only as a linear term, and the other, `time`, is modeled using a cubic polynomial.

If you had three actual factors, there are contexts in which testing pairwise comparisons among all factor-level combinations, though even then, I think most people would do only selected such comparisons, e.g., simple comparisons of one factor for each combinations of the other two. Otherwise, you lose a huge amount of power in multiplicity adjustments for the scads of possible comparisons, many of which you probably don't really care about.

But with polynomial trends in the model, I would *never* involve them in pairwise comparisons. Also, anything more than two levels of `NFC` is superfluous because a comparison of any two different values is a test of its linear trend. So one suggestion I would make is to test a suitable set of interaction contrasts. For example

```
emm1 = emmeans(model5, ~ NFC * support * time,
    at = list(time = 1:4, NFC = c(-1,1)),
    type = "response", lmer.df = "satterthwaite")
emm1  # list the estimates

contrast(emm1, interaction = c("pairwise", "pairwise", "poly"))
```

This would give you tests of interactions of pairwise comparisons of the first two factors with linear, quadratic, and cubic contrasts of the time trend.

There are other approaches, for example, using `emtrends()` to estimate the polynomial trends for `time`, and then conducting pairwise comparisons of those. See `vignette("interactions", "emmeans")` for more discussion and examples.

Comment: I also suggest supplementing this with some visual interpretations of the model, e.g., `plot(emm1)` or `emmip(emm1, support ~ time | NFC)` In these plots, it might be helpful to include more `NFC` values so you can visualize the different possibilities as it changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the alternatives! It helped me immensely to get a clear picture of my model. Thanks again for addressing my questions.